# Looping through an array of elements and hiding element if condition true

Tags: jquery, html

I have a carousel and within each of the images a nested URL, some of the URLs will contain text others won't. The problem I am facing is that the styling for the URL is appearing even if there is no text for that URL. I would like to hide the URL if there is no text. Below is my HTML structure

```js
var CaptionItems = $('#slideshow').find('.Caption');

$(CaptionItems).each(function() {
  if (CaptionItems.text() === "") {
    $('#slideshow').find('.Caption').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow" class="owl-wrapper-outer">
  <div class="owl-wrapper owl-origin">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="Caption">Nothing to see, move along!</a>
      <img src="#" alt="barbady.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item" style="width: 679px;">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="Caption"></a>
      <img src="#" alt="rubics.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="owl-item" style="width: 679px;">
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="Caption">Some Text</a>
      <img src="#">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I've checked this in the console, it seems to be hiding what is contained in `CaptionItems` but not what's on the actual page. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no slideshow element in the markup you have added

Comment: Good point, I forgot to add the id to the top div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because you need to reference the current element's text within the iteration, not all the elements together. Try this;

```
var CaptionItems = $('#slideshow').find('.Caption');
$(CaptionItems).each(function () {
   if ($(this).text().trim() === "") {
       $(this).hide();
   }
});
```

Note the use of the `this` keyword above, and calling `hide()` on the `.Caption` element directly.

Also note that you can make this code simpler with the use of `filter()`:

```
$('#slideshow .Caption').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim() == '';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'this' keyword to hide the current item in the loop.

```js
$('.Caption').each(function () {
 if ($(this).text().trim() === "") {
 $(this).hide();
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
 <div class="owl-wrapper owl-origin">
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#" class="Caption">Nothing to see, move along!</a>
  <img src="#" alt="barbady.jpg">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 679px;">
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#" class="Caption"></a>
  <img src="#" alt="rubics.png">
</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item" style="width: 679px;">
   <div class="item">
   <a href="#" class="Caption">Some Text</a>
   <img src="#">
   </div>
</div>
```